# Ao Calcular quantidade maior e menor que a Média retorna erro no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Nas Colunas:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN cqd.queuetime < AVG(cqd.queuetime) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Qtde < Média' e
SUM(CASE WHEN cqd.queuetime > AVG(cqd.queuetime) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Qtde > Média',
```

retorna o seguinte erro no SQL SERVER 2018:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado!

script completo:

```
select  csq.csqname as Cqs, CONVERT(TIME,ccd.startdatetime,10) "Time", r.resourcename AS Agente,
SUM(CASE WHEN cqd.queuetime > 20  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Total(>20)',
MAX(cqd.queuetime) as '> Número',
MAX(ccd.connecttime) as '>Tempo',
SUM(CASE WHEN asd.eventtype = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Logados',
SUM(CASE WHEN asd.eventtype = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Em Atendimento',
--qtde < média qdt qtd duração de chamadas < média
SUM(CASE WHEN cqd.queuetime < AVG(cqd.queuetime) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Qtde > Média',
MIN(cqd.queuetime) as 'Menor tempo de ligação',
AVG(cqd.queuetime) as 'Tempo médio de atendimento',
STDEVP(cqd.queuetime) as 'Desvio Padrão',
MAX(cqd.queuetime) as 'Maior tempo de ligação',
--qtde > média qtd duração de chamadas > média 
SUM(CASE WHEN cqd.queuetime > AVG(cqd.queuetime) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Qtde > Média',
SUM(CASE WHEN cqd.disposition = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Atendidas',
SUM(CASE WHEN cqd.disposition = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Abandonadas'

from [resource] r

INNER JOIN teamcsqmapping on r.assignedteamid = teamcsqmapping.teamid 
INNER JOIN contactservicequeue csq on teamcsqmapping.csqid = csq.contactservicequeueid
INNER JOIN contactcalldetail ccd on r.resourceid = ccd.destinationID and ccd.destinationtype = 1
JOIN contactqueuedetail cqd on csq.contactservicequeueid = cqd.targetid and cqd.targettype = 0
INNER JOIN agentstatedetail asd on r.resourceid = asd.agentid

WHERE 
CONVERT(TIME,ccd.startdatetime,10) BETWEEN '14:00' AND '14:59'

GROUP BY csqname, CONVERT(TIME,ccd.startdatetime,10), r.resourcename
ORDER BY resourcename, 2 ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro é bem claro:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Ou em tradução livre:

> Não é possível executar uma função agregada em uma expressão contendo uma agregada ou subquery.

O problema é que é impossível interpretar o seu comando em termos de agregação. Aparentemente você quer indicar quais os registros que estão fora da média. Para isso você deve definir as `queries` separadamente, uma com as médias e a outra com os registros em si.

Um exemplo seria o seguinte:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN t.valor < x.media THEN 'Qtde > Média'
         WHEN t.valor > x.media THEN 'Qtde < Média'
         ELSE 'Qtde igual a média'
       END AS conclusao
  FROM tabela t
       INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(t.valor) AS media,
                          t.id_grupo
                     FROM tabela t
                    GROUP BY t.id_grupo) x ON x.id_grupo = t.id_grupo
```

Comment: Poderia me mandar um exemplo, por favor?

Comment: @ThiagoSimão vou montar um exemplo simplificado, já que não temos a estrutura das suas tabelas

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Usando OVER se consegue comparar linha a linha com a médiacpor exemplo  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017